# Service Worker determine number of clients

Tags: javascript, vue.js, service-worker

We've got a SaaS app that's PWA capable and we're using Workbox for the grunt work. Up to now we've been following the tried and trusted recipe of displaying an update is available banner to the users, prompting them to update their web app.

Viewing usage data (via Sentry.io) we've noticed that most users simply seem to ignore the update banner and continue with the version they're on.

So we're looking at trying something different. This is to perform the update automatically when they change the route in the web app (when we know there's an update available).

Testing this shows that it does work. However there's a side-effect, and that is if they've got web app open in multiple tabs, then all the tabs get updated. This could be problematic for users' if they've got an un-saved form open in one of the tabs in the background - they'll potentially loose their work.

This happens during this piece of code:

```js
// app shell page, created lifecycle hook
document.addEventListener('swUpdated', this.SetPwaRegistration, { once: true })
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', () => {
  if (this.refreshing) {
    return
  }
  this.refreshing = true
  window.location.reload()
})

// app shell page, method in methods collection
SetPwaRegistration (event) {
  // call mutation to pass the registration object to Vuex
  this.PWA_REGISTRATION_SET({ pwaRegistration: event.detail })
}

// main.js
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  // retrieve the registration object from Vuex
  const pwaRegistration = app.$store.getters.pwaRegistration
  if (pwaRegistration) {
      pwaRegistration.waiting.postMessage('skipWaiting')
  }
})
```

*the above code is from our Vue.js app code-base, the `this.refreshing` is set to `false` by default in the `data` property collection.*

What I'd like to know if whether it is possible to determine if the Service Worker has only one client under it's control (i.e. the web app is only open in 1 browser tab), and if this is the case, the auto-update can happen without potential issues. If there's more than one client, then we'll display the update banner as usual.

---

As a brief update to this, I've come across code examples similar to this:

```js
self.clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
  const clientCount = clients.length
  // store count of client in Vuex
})
```

Which looks like an option (i.e. count how many clients there are, store this in Vuex store), I'm just not sure where it should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to orchestrate the reload from entirely within the service worker, you can effectively do that by using the [`WindowClient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowClient) interface to programmatically navigate to whatever the current URL is, which is roughly equivalent to a reload.

The two things to keep in in mind that [`navigate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowClient/navigate) will only work on `WindowClient`s (not `Worker`s) and that you can only call it if the service worker controls the `WindowClient`.

Putting that together, here's something to try:

```js
// This can be run, e.g., in a `message` handler in your SW:
self.clients.matchAll({
  // These options are actually the defaults, but just
  // to be explicit:
  includeUncontrolled: false,
  type: 'window',
}).then((clients) => {
  if (clients.length === 1) {
    clients[0].navigate(clients[0].url);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. If I understand correctly, would this then only reload that particular tab (client) that 'received' the update? I.e. I would then be able to remove the `navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', ...)` bit of code which refreshes all the clients?

Comment: I think I understand.. in the sw.js, where I currently have `if (e.data === 'skipWaiting') { self.skipWaiting() }` I'd replace this with your suggestion?

Comment: You'd still need to keep the logic around triggering `skipWaiting()` if you want to ensure that the newly installed service worker activates first. That code snippet I posted is a direct alternative to calling `window.location.reload()`, ensuring that the reload only happens when there is exactly one controlled client window open. I was under the impression that's what your goal was.

Comment: Thanks again Jeff, yeah, your impression is about right. I'll do some more playing round with the code sample. I'll get there :) Much appreciated.